# app crashing on uitableview load

Tags: ios, uitableview

My app keeps crashing on app load with the culprit being the line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"payment_frequency"];
```

The error I get is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a538e0'
```

self.searchResults does have 4 objects in it as it is an array. Each object as the follows:

```
    {
    50316462547c6dbdf2000005 =     {
    "created_at" = "2012-08-19T17:10:42-0500";
            id = 50316462547c6dbdf2000005;
            "payment_frequency" = "One Time";
            "user_id" = 1;
    };

    50316462547c6dbdf2000005 =     {
    "created_at" = "2012-08-19T17:10:42-0500";
            id = 50316462547c6dbdf2000005;
            "payment_frequency" = "One Time";
            "user_id" = 1;
    };

    50316462547c6dbdf2000005 =     {
    "created_at" = "2012-08-19T17:10:42-0500";
            id = 50316462547c6dbdf2000005;
            "payment_frequency" = "One Time";
            "user_id" = 1;
    };


    50316462547c6dbdf2000005 =     {
    "created_at" = "2012-08-19T17:10:42-0500";
            id = 50316462547c6dbdf2000005;
            "payment_frequency" = "One Time";
            "user_id" = 1;
    };

}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchResultsViewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"payment_frequency"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the @property declaration of searchResults?

Comment: `searchResults` is **not** an array. It is a dictionary. You might need to transform your data collection into an array after you load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that your are sending objectAtIndex: to a dictionary object, not an array.

You have :

- a wrong declaration
  or
- a memory issue (reusing free memory)